# Grid form layout using jsf (Jdeveloper & ADF)

Tags: grid, oracle-adf

I am trying to build a 6x6 grid layout. In each cell, there will be an input check box. I want to bind the checkboxes to my backing bean in a "consecutive fashion"...meaning, I would like to be able to iterate over the checkboxes to see whether they are checked or not. Basically, there must be an underlying data model. For example, you can drag over and drop off as a table, any item in the data control palette. Then in my application module, I can modify the view object as I wish before I save to the database. Now if I have a table with 36 rows and two columns (one is Id, one is Numeric (1 or 0)). I would like to drag over that table and drop off as a Grid that will enable a user to update each of the rows by selecting or 'un-selecting' a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use for each or Iterator component. They iterate over some array/collection and repeat elements enclosed within those components. You can check how Oracle does Dynamic Table (when you drag view object instance from application module to a page, choose dynamic table option)  to get and idea.
try :
http://jobinesh.blogspot.com/2010/06/model-driven-approach-for-building.html
http://blogs.oracle.com/shay/2010/10/adf_faces_dynamic_tags_-_for_a.html

also try google with "dynamic form adf"

Comment: Hey, thanks so much Amir...I have started trying out something else. I'm now using selectBooleanCheckbox(es). I lay them out in a grid using h:panelGrid. this works well, however, to accomplish what I want, I need to get the values of the checkboxes in a list (ArrayList)...so I can change the properties (for example: disable one, or make it selected)...Any ideas how to get a collection of checkboxes? Thank you.

Comment: You have answer in after second question "get a list of af:selectBooleanCheckbox adf" . I hope it will work for you